How do you manage to keep sanity when having high equity
I am roughly high upper class, more value less loan. Now the thing is that with my equity valuation comes a lot of work. Example I have small Airbnb business on top of that I rent out some office space in paralel I am working full time as softwareengeneer. I have to manage my budget, my side businesses and activities and on top I need to balance with my family I have 3 children. My main issue is multithreading so I there are only so much things I can do in paralel my business is not that huge to keep a full time employee , but this year I was pressed to do so. I was very frustrated to find out this employee created for me relativly similar amount of work as he actualy resolved,.
So the question What strategies are using the rich to keep sanity and work life balance, My wife is expecting me to be a normal husband but I dont think I realy am.

The answer you need has nothing to do with "the rich" or equity,  and everything to do with managing time, priorities, and expectations both at work and at home. There have been past questions about those topics; you should review them, and ask a new, specific, question if there's something in those answers you don't understand.

@keshlam what do you mean ? I am just trying to scope roughly how much equity/work I am talking about

I'm not sure what you mean by "how much equity/work ". You have whatever work your job entails. You have whatever equity in the company you have.

@keshlam can you point me out to the question/answer I am not. sure how to search it ?

@keshlam my opinion is that money creates work. More money more work , that is my statement. You dont agree ?

Click on the tags you selected to find other questions carrying the same tags.

No, I don't agree. Work creates money. You get to decide how much your work is worth to you; the company gets to decide how much it is worth to them and what the priorities are. If there is a disconnect, you may be in the wrong job, or your expectations may be unrealistic.

Who decides what jobs you do, what businesses you own, what priority you give to your family? You do, surely? Pick what you want to focus on.

@mattfreake I don@t see it this way. Half of my property is inheritence I can not just dump it or sell it or ignore it. I dont think this is an option.

@keshlam but. I am both the company and the employee. Should I develop a splity brain syndrom ?

Why @Pesho ? It sounds like it's causing you lots of stress. Talk to your family members who would be unhappy if you sold it and explain.

I see. Sell all, move to a low cost place abroud. Live hapily after to the end of my days yeiiiii....

Not at all Pesho. How do you think other people manage who don't have multiple jobs?

@mattfreake No idea honestlly :D

Sell what is more trouble than it is worth. Making the most money possible is not the goal. Make enough money to live the kind of life you want to live. If you really need all of this to achieve that, consider whether the kind of life you want really is affordable and either recalibrate or accept that you are going to work yourself to death achieving it. You really can walk away from a good thing to get a better one, and money is not the only way to keep score.

There is a misconception that rich people sit on their luxury yachts and sip Champagne all day. You are discovering this is not the case.  Assets must be managed and most "passive" income streams are anything but that. As an example, I saw a video that touted the best passive side hustles, and the punch line was "you have to keep your customers engaged". Keeping your customers engaged is not easy, and certainly not passive.
One must choose which income streams to focus on. As a software engineer you have a high relative salary to the rest of your community, with the opportunity to make one filthy rich.  However, not all 80+ hour week startups pan out. Many have stock options that are worthless. So, there is a first choice, do you work a startup that could make you very wealthy or a job that pays well and is secure with good benefits?
If you want to be an Airbnb owner, then you probably have to work on increasing your holdings.  Do the minimum at your full-time job to not be fired, and work aggressively on employing a plan to make that your primary source of income.
For many engineers, they focusing on investing their larger than normal salary.  In the US many firms offer incentives to do just that, with matching contributions. Long-term investing can be a very passive income source with healthy returns. Data shows that few professional investors can actually beat a passive investor approach that is easy to implement.  In a few mouse clicks one can setup an investment strategy that is both automated and does not need to be touched for years.
As far as family, engaging in business opportunities takes time.  What are you going to give up in order to be the kind of father you want to be?
These are not easy choices, and you have to engineer your life, so you are the kind of husband, father, engineer and businessperson you want to be. However, you need to be deliberate in doing so.

Exactly. Decide what your priorities are, what your actual needs are, how much time and effort you are willing to give to each item. If the inherited property is more than you want to deal with, unload it -- to the relatives if you and/or they  really care that much about keeping it in the family,, or in the open market -- and put the money into something that requires less attention. Or hire a property manager to deal with those for you -- that will reduce your income, but the stress reduction may be more than worth that cost. Everyone makes these tradeoffs.
